# root route not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In routes.rb file: `root "pages#index"`

pages_controller.rb file

```
  class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def index
      render 'home'
    end

    def about
    end
  end
```

view named `home.html.haml`

`rake routes` returns

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern        Controller#Action
   home GET  /home(.:format)    pages#home
  about GET  /about(.:format)   pages#about
```

localhost just says "We're sorry, but something went wrong.", the console says `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/home"):`

On Rails 4.2.0.beta2

*Edit for Rails version and console error

Comment: Which version of rails?

Comment: @nithin localhost just says "We're sorry, but something went wrong.", the console says `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/home"):`

Comment: Please show your routes file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `rake routes` says that a `GET /home` will match `pages#home`, the home action in pages controller.

Can you show us more of your `routes.rb` file ?

Moreover, why don't you rename your home.html.haml file to index.html.haml file, thus your index action can become

```
def index
end
```

If you don't specify which view to render, Rails will try to find a view with the name of your action.

Answer (score 0):

I would update your routes.rb file to:

```
root 'pages#index'

get '/home',  to: 'pages#index'
get '/about', to: 'pages#about'
```

As suggested by Benjamin, I do think that it would be a better design to rename your home.html.erb to index.html.erb. This way you can remove the `render 'home'` from your index method.

What is odd is that your `rake routes` output says that /home will be redirected to pages#home, which is a controller method that you don't have.